# Store my android app data to cloud database also how to establish the connection

Tags: android

I'm working on android app, where I want the data entered in the app to be stored in cloud platform, can please some one help me how to establish the connection to the cloud and store the data in cloud?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Do you have a specific problem? Before asking a question one should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). For additional information read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I'm new in development, so I'm keen to know how to use the cloud database, as we use mysql and others... Help me how to start with this...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for showing you how to do stuff. Read the three links from my comment above to find out which questions are appropriate for Stack Overflow and which are not. If you want to know how to do stuff than Google is your friend. As soon as you encounter a specific programming problem you can come back here and ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create webservice for that. Take help of this link

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

It will store all your data on server. You can access it with urls.

Create response in Json format. you need to parse those Json objects from server